# Can I fly out of England within my quarantine period?

Tags: uk, covid-19, quarantine

If I fly into England from a country on the quarantine list (thus requiring me to isolate myself at a single address for two weeks) can I fly out of England within that two weeks?

Comment: Just to note that regulations are different in England, Scotland Wales and Northern Ireland.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the full quarantine period have to be observed for short trips of less than 14 days to England?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158861/does-the-full-quarantine-period-have-to-be-observed-for-short-trips-of-less-than)

Comment: Where in England do you plan to self-isolate, and in what type of accommodation? In some areas, you cannot stay in a private home, for example https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-54373904

Comment: I've found that the answer to this question in Germany is "no one really knows but there is also no enforemcent or controls and no one seem to care". The high level statement "you must proceed directly to your location of quarantine" is not backed up with any details of what specifically you can do or not. Can you rent a car, take a train, ride the bus, take a plane ? Of course you are not supposed to do any of this, but you can't stay at the airport either. So something has to give here and it seems largely unspecified.

Comment: @Hilmar [How to travel to the place where you are self-isolating](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-how-to-self-isolate-when-you-travel-to-the-uk/coronavirus-covid-19-how-to-self-isolate-when-you-travel-to-the-uk)

Comment: @BernhardDöbler: Cool, thanks. I did not found anything like this for Germany. Your link also states "If you have coronavirus symptoms, it is important that you do not travel by public transport" If we you develop symptoms during travel and before arrival: what are you supposed to do ?

Comment: @Hilmar, get a hotel room at the airport or travel by your own car (if you have one there) I might call the friend I expect to stay with to come and collect me. (But we both agreed not to travel now.)